# How can I extract hand features from these images?

Tags: python, opencv

I have two different types of images (which I cannot post due to reputation, so I've linked them.):

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rj76.jpg) [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P7cL.jpg)

I was trying to extract hand features from the images using OpenCV and Python. Which kinda looks like this:

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5,5), 0)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
retval, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray, 70, 255, / cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow('image', thresh1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The result of which looks like this:

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDLT6.jpg) [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cKtz.jpg)

The change in background in the second image is messing with the `cv2.threshold()` function and its not getting the skin parts right. Is there a way to do this right?

As a follow up question, what is the best way to extract hand features? I tried a HaaR Cascade and I didn't really get results? Should I train my own cascade? What other options do I have?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by hand features? Do you want to extract only hands from the image? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Also useful: how representative are these 2 images of your expected input? Are all people seated in the same pose? Are they photographed under controlled lighting (ie, all photographed in the same studio)? Any other useful information on constraints in the system?

Comment: @DevashishPrasad Yes, I want to extract the contours of the hand.

Comment: @Chungzuwalla The clothing of the people change, but the lighting and posture is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say based on a sample size of two images, but I would try OpenCV's [Integral Channel Features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_channel_feature) (ChnFtrs), which are like supercharged Haar features that can take cues from colour as well as any other image channels you care to create and provide.

- In any case, you are going to have to train your own cascades. Separate cascades for front and profile shots of course.
- Take out your thresholding by skin colour, because as you've already noticed, it may throw away some or all of the hands depending on the actual subject's skin colour and lighting. ChnFtrs will do the skin detection for you more robustly than a fixed threshold can. (Though for future reference, all humans are actually [orange](https://www.google.com/patents/US8358812) :))
- You could eliminate some false positives by only detecting within a bounding box of where you expect the hands to be.
- Try both RGB and YUV channels to see what works best. You could also throw in the results of edge detection (say, Canny, maximised across your 3 colour channels) for good measure. At the end, you could cull channels which are underused to save processing if necessary.
- If you have much variation in hand pose, you may need to group similar poses and train a separate ChnFtrs cascade for each group. Individual cascades do not have a branching structure, so they do not cope well when the positive samples are disjoint in parameter space. This is, AFAIK, a bit of an unexplored area.

A correctly trained ChnFtrs cascade (or several) may give you a bounding box for the hands, which will help in extracting hand contours, but it can't exclude invalid contours within the same bounding box. Most other object detection routines will also have this problem.

Another option, which may be better/simpler than ChnFtrs, is LINEMOD (a current favourite of mine). It has the advantage that there's no complex training process, nor any training time needed.